# asp.net mvc 3 Save button that links to specific page after saving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have a save button that saves values entered by the user to a database. I would also like to have the button link the user back to the home page when pressed if the values have been saved successfully. The click function i currently have is below. I know it's not a hard request but i can't quite get it to work.

```
$("#saveButton").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/UpdateParam",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/Json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ assessments: assessments }),
                    success: function (d) {
                        if (d === false) {
                            alert("DID NOT SAVE");
                        }
                        if (d === true) {
                            alert("Readings Saved");
                            $("#listOfParamsDiv").empty();
                        }

                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out. Wow i feel dumb. All i did was add these two lines if the if(d===true) loop:

var link = "/Home/Index";
window.location.href = link;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a home button click event in jQuery Success function

Example:

```
if (d === true) {
     alert("Readings Saved");
     $("#listOfParamsDiv").empty();
     $("#homeButtonLink").trigger("click");
   }
```

I think this is what your expecting.